# Left Join with distinct/grouping of a single column

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, coas, which stores file information such as the part number, rq (rq can only be used once for a part number) and location where the file is saved. I also have a product names table which stores the names for each specific part number.

Examples:

**coas**

```
id | pn  | rq  | loc
0  | 123 | 147 | uploads/123147.pdf
1  | 123 | 258 | uploads/12258.pdf
2  | 102 | 147 | uploads/102147.pdf
```

**product_names**

```
id | pn  | name
0  | 123 | test product
1  | 102 | test product2
```

I have a live search feature using jQuery, php and mysql.

For each part number/name I want each rq and location so that the specific file may be opened. Search results would look like:

```
(123) test product
147, 258  (these will link to the actual and formatting would look different but just trying to get the idea of what kind of results I need)

(102) test product2
147
```

I was using join left to get the product names attached to the part numbers in the coas table (I added the product_names table, so not all part numbers have a name associated with them  yet). I can get the results, but i get each part number separate with its rq and file, i am wondering how i can get the pn and its name group to display only once with the files for that product listed for each product. i have been searching but can't seem to figure out how to make this work. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps `Group_Concat()`  [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)  which will cobine multiple rows into one and allow you to list the values of each row in a single field... though I don't fully understand the question

Comment: Put the query you are already using

Comment: i have only been messing around with different queries t try and get this to work how i want, but i am able to combine the tables using:
SELECT coas.*, product_names.name FROM coas LEFT JOIN product_names ON coas.pn=product_names.pn ORDER BY coas.pn

but im not sure how to display each part number only once, with the matching different rq/loc for each part number/name

Comment: [link](http://s32.postimg.org/4humsuk1x/sql.png)<br>here is a screenshot from some of the resulting query

Comment: [link](http://s32.postimg.org/ghpw58xz9/sql2.png)